# Vaadin 8 grid multiple selection model get row on event

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I am using multiple row selection in vaadin 8 grid, I need an event that gives me the selected row object upon clicking the selection checkbox not the row click.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `grid.addSelectionListener(..)` for this. `SelectionEvent` is fired each time you change selection, i.e. click the checkbox in case of multiselection model. In case `SelectionEvent` is instance of `MultiSelectionEvent` you can get the last added selection

https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.3/docs/api/com/vaadin/event/selection/MultiSelectionEvent.html#getNewSelection--

Or removed selection

https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.3/8.3.3/docs/api/com/vaadin/event/selection/MultiSelectionEvent.html#getRemovedSelection--